# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'

Tags: c#

I writing the application in listview CRUD with XML.

I have a problem when getting rows to the listview. Error appear when I try to convert List<> to Object.

Here my code:

```
    public IEnumerable<object> GetRows()
    {
        List<DataLstViewEmail> rows = new List<DataLstViewEmail>();

        if (File.Exists("MyData.xml"))
        {
            // Create the query 
            var rowsFromFile = from c in XDocument.Load(
                        "MyData.xml").Elements(
                        "Data").Elements("Rows").Elements("Row")
                               select c;

            // Execute the query 
            foreach (var row in rowsFromFile)
            {
                rows.Add(new DataLstViewEmail(row.Element("col1").Value,
                        row.Element("col2").Value));
            }
        }
        return rows;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us code for `DataLstViewEmail` ?

Comment: You are probably using an old compiler version, or < 4.0 C# version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do

```
public List<DataLstViewEmail> GetRows()
{
```

instead of

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetRows()
{
```

Comment: That is changing method signature and it is not a useful approach. You should return an interface when you can instead of returning a concrete type.

Comment: @dotctor but there he can't. The best he can do is to return an `IEnumerable<DataLstViewEmail>`

Comment: Every `List<T>` is `IEnumerable<object>` unless T is a value type. I think `DataLstViewEmail` is a struct.

Answer (score 0):

Every `List<T>` is `IEnumerable<object>` unless `T` is a value type. I suspect that `DataLstViewEmail` is a struct.

You can simply cast the `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<object>`. Just change the return statement

```
return rows.Cast<object>();
```